# MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one object on DetailView

Tags: django, django-views

views.py

```
class ArticleDetail(DetailView):
    model = Article

    def get_queryset(self):
        public_articles = Article.objects.filter(is_public=True)
        private_authored_articles = Article.objects.filter(is_public=False, author=self.request.user)
        return public_articles.union(private_authored_articles)
```

urls.py

```
path('articles/<slug:slug>/', views.ArticleDetail.as_view(), name='article-detail')
```

models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, editable=False)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I want users to be able to see a detail view of a specific article identified by a unique slug. A user should have access to the detail view of an article if either it is public or it was authored by the current user and is not public. Author is a foreign key to my user model. I have this same get_queryset() logic in my ListView and it gives me exactly what I want however when I click on any of the articles to request the detail view I get the MultipleObjectsReturned exception. Another note is django_debug_toolbar is saying the view is sending duplicated queries. The number of queries and the number of objects returned are equal so I need to figure out why it is sending duplicate queries, possibly caused by the foreign key relationship.

Comment: What is your `url` in `urls.py`? Is this is whole `ArticleDetail` View?

Comment: I am also overriding get_context_data, sending some extra context. Omitted that part since that should not be the cause for the exception.

Comment: What is the slug part in the URL? Where do you do the filtering based on that? May be the same slug is present in multiple articles?

Comment: slug is a SlugField on Article with constraint unique=True. So to answer your question, no, the same slug is not present in multiple articles. Queryset should not filter based on slug. It's purpose is to retrieve possible candidate articles to be displayed in the DetailView.

Comment: Is the `slug_field` set properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Article.objects.exclude(Q(is_public=False), 
                                  ~Q(author=self.request.user))
```

I found the solution! I did not know about Q objects before making this post. The ability to negate a Q object is really handy in this case. The logic here is I am excluding only non-public articles by users other than the current user.

Answer (score 0):

In your **views.py** check below parameters and make sure that to define `slug` field as below:

```
class ArticleDetail(DetailView):
    model = Article
    slug_field = 'slug_field'  # Replace `slug_field` with your SlugField on Article model
    slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'

    def get_queryset(self):
        public_articles = Article.objects.filter(is_public=True)
        authored_articles = Article.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
        return public_articles.union(authored_articles)
```